# Monthly trend comparison using tables in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, date-comparison

I'm quite new to GDS and I've been experimenting with the comparison date range to see the increase in % between current and previous month

I've managed to get a slight result but it's not showing the correct % increase which I have manually calculated to confirm.

The values are

> No of Reviews (calculation)
>
> July - **379** reviews / **314** positive reviews = **82.85%**
>
> August - **480** reviews / **458** positive reviews = **95.42%**
>
> *Manually Calculated Difference = 12.57%*
>
> GDS Comparison Difference = 15.2%

The date column itself is formatted as "YYYYMMDD" and I've tried the comparison and calculation field options on the metric but to no avail

It feels like I am getting a comparative % rather than a direct increase

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated as I have tried the GDS forum several times but there is very little activity on there

Thanks so much

Dan

Comment: Hi Daniel. You are getting a comparative %. You can only really do something about this in your data source. What do you use?

Comment: Hi @Bobbylank, the data is from a Google Sheet. The metric itself is a calculated field which is based on the count of "Positive" reviews / Total No of reviews

Not really sure what I would need to do to get the right results as I've only been working with GDS for about 3 weeks now and for the most part my calculations have just been done in Google Sheets/Excel and converted to tables to produce the month on month trends

Any help/links or ideas would be muchly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal but to do this in GDS you need to create a new column in Google Sheets which is literally the values you need from the previous month. I.e.

```
date      |reviews|pos reviews|prev month reviews|prev month pos reviews|
2019-08-01|480    |458        |379               |     314              |
```

You can then create 2 calculated fields for this month % positive and last month % positive and a 3rd for the difference.

There are other wyas you can try to do this but they get a bit messy and manual so that's probably a good starting point. GDS is great in some ways (cost being one!) but a little limited in others!

Answer (score 0):

On the style on your table, under `show compare`, check `Show Absolute Change` to get the exact difference.